# Bezout relation multipliers for the gcd of two numbers

Tags: number-theory

The gcd of 28 and 49 can be expressed as linear combination as 28x+49y then (x,y) =

1. (1,1)
2. (1,-1)
3. (1,2)
4. (3,1)

Comment: Have you computed the GCD?  Then you can just try all the answers.  None of them work.  Can you find the correct answer?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify the title : relationship ux+vy="gcd" is called  Bezout relationship.

Comment: $(2/-1)$ is a possibility.